# How to pass a list from the view to the controller in Spring MVC with thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have an html page to edit a list of persons.
When the page is opened the controller gets the list of persons from the db and binds to the view.
That works fine.

Then the user edits the data and clicks save.
Now I need to submit the edited data of each person to the controller so that the controller can save the edits.

I'm trying to do that using `@ModelAttribute ArrayList<Person>` as shown below but it's not working.
The arraylist comes empty.

How do I do for the arraylist to come filled with all of the persons objects from the form?

View

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<form action="editperson" method="post">
<th:block th:each="person : ${personBind}">

    Name:
    <input type="text" th:value="${person.name}" />
    </br></br>

    Age:
    <input type="text" th:value="${person.age}" />
    </br></br>

</th:block>
</br></br>
<input type="submit" name="btnSaveEdit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editperson", params = "btnSaveEdit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEditPerson(@ModelAttribute ArrayList<Person> personsList){
        //save edit code here
        return "editperson";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring MVC with Thymeleaf does indeed use model attributes to store data for the Thymeleaf pages. [This guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) shows how to load data from a form into the application. Try wrapping the ArrayList inside of a custom object and access the list via that object as a ModelAttribute rather than working with an ArrayList directly.

The saveEditPerson method should probably be named "saveEditPersons" since you are parsing a list of persons rather than just one.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The fact that I'm calling the arraylist as "personsList" is not the problem. I could certainly call it whatever I want. That’s not where the mapping occurs. Have done that several times before(when it’s a single object, not a list) and it works just fine. Anyway, I did that change to test it out and didn’t work. Also took a look at the guide you provided. But it does not have an example for a list. For single objects I already know how to do.

Comment: You're making sure that you store your list of users as a ModelAttribute before you load the view, I presume? And yes, the example is for a single object, though arguably an ArrayList is just a somewhat special object that stores references to other objects in an array managed by internal logic.

Comment: what you mean by storing the list of users as a ModelAttribute? What I'm doing is what is in the code above. That code would work if it was a single object instead of an arraylist.

Comment: You need to populate the list of persons before you display the page with the edit form, so there should be a RequestMapping for the GET method, as well. Also, you could try wrapping the ArrayList inside of a custom object so that you do handle a single object. Of course this would mean that you would have to refactor the code in your Thymeleaf page so that you access the list inside of that custom object.

Comment: Yes, I do populate the list of persons for edit in a GET method. I mentioned on the post: "When the page is opened the controller gets the list of persons from the db and binds to the view. That works fine.". So didn't want to add that code here in the question. You are right about the idea of creating a custom object to wrap the list. I followed the example on the following link (which does exactly that) and it worked! Thanks for your help. https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list